# Convergence of definite integrals given unknowns.

Tags: convergence-divergence

Given the following equation,
$$
\int_{1}^{2} \frac{1}{x(\ln x)^{a}} dx
$$
I am supposed to find the condition on the constant $a$ such that the above integral is convergent.

Substituting $u = \ln(x)$, we get

$$
\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{1}{x} 
$$

Where the integral

$$
\int_{1}^{2} \frac{1}{x(\ln x)^{a}} dx = \int_{0}^{\ln 2} \frac{du}{dx}\frac{1}{u^{a}}dx = \int_{0}^{ln2} \frac{1}{u^{a}}du
$$

simplifies to

$$
\frac{(\ln 2)^{1-a}}{1-a}
$$

When $a = 1$, the above diverges. However, I am unsure of what values the above equation converges to, i.e when $a>1$ or $a<1$

Comment: Can you explain your step from $\int_{0}^{ln2} \frac{1}{u^{a}}du$ to $\frac{(ln2)^{1-a}}{1-a}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's be a bit more formal here. First of all, it indeed suffices to consider the transformed integral
$$
\int_0^{\ln(2)} \frac 1{u^a}\,du = \int_0^{\ln(2)} u^{-a}\,du.
$$
Note that because of the possible division by zero, this is an *improper* integral. In other words, the quantity that we're after is the limit
$$
\lim_{b \to 0^+} \int_b^{\ln(2)} u^{-a}\,du.
$$
In the case that $a \neq 1$, this can be written as
$$
\lim_{b \to 0^+} \int_b^{\ln(2)} u^{-a}\,du = \lim_{b \to 0^+} \left(\frac{\ln(2)^{1-a}}{1-a} - \frac{b^{1-a}}{1-a}\right).
$$
What can we say about this limit when $a > 1$? When $a < 1$? What does the integral become in the case that $a = 1$?

Comment: When $k = 1$, the integral diverges. When $k>1$, the evaluation of the limit of $b^{1-k}$ is $\infty$, so the integral diverges. So when $k<1$, the integral converges?

Comment: Sorry, I changed the $a$ to a $k$ at some point. In any case, yes: that's all correct. In particular, when $k < 1$, the evaluation of the limit is $0$.

Comment: Yes thanks for the explanation and clarification!

Answer (score -1):

Take $x=e^t$, then
$$I=\int_{1}^{2} \frac{dx}{x \ln^a x}=\int_{0}^{\ln 2} \frac{dt}{t^a}=\frac{1}{1-a}|_{0}^{\ln 2}= \frac{1}{1-a}[(\ln 2)^{1-a}-0^{1-a}]= \text{finite if}~ a<1.$$

Answer (score -1):

We have that

$$\int_{1}^{2} \frac{1}{x(\ln x)^{a}} dx=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(1+x)(\ln (1+x))^{a}} dx$$

with $(\ln (1+x))^{a} \sim x^a $ as $x \to 0^+$ and therefore

$$\frac{1}{(1+x)(\ln (1+x))^{a}} \sim \frac1{x^a}$$

and we can conclude by limit comparison test.